# heroku logs sh: 1: concurrently: not found

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, npm, package

```
2017-10-08T20:06:11.093118+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2017-10-08T20:06:15.431068+00:00 app[web.1]:
2017-10-08T20:06:15.431083+00:00 app[web.1]: > shopping-cart-app@0.1.0 start /app
2017-10-08T20:06:15.431084+00:00 app[web.1]: > concurrently "npm run server" "npm run client"
2017-10-08T20:06:15.439379+00:00 app[web.1]: sh: 1: concurrently: not found
2017-10-08T20:06:15.446591+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! file sh
2017-10-08T20:06:15.431085+00:00 app[web.1]:
2017-10-08T20:06:15.447135+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno ENOENT
2017-10-08T20:06:15.447368+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! syscall spawn
2017-10-08T20:06:15.446893+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2017-10-08T20:06:15.453425+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2017-10-08T20:06:15.448865+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! shopping-cart-app@0.1.0 start: `concurrently "npm run server" "npm run client"`
2017-10-08T20:06:15.453636+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the shopping-cart-app@0.1.0 start script.
2017-10-08T20:06:15.464269+00:00 app[web.1]:
2017-10-08T20:06:15.453115+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
2017-10-08T20:06:15.453824+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2017-10-08T20:06:15.469282+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2017-10-08T20:06:15.469426+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2017-10-08T20_06_15_456Z-debug.log
2017-10-08T20:06:15.625015+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2017-10-08T20:06:15.627831+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2017-10-08T20:06:15.609086+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2017-10-08T20:06:20.543684+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2017-10-08T20:06:23.048216+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2017-10-08T20:06:22.944636+00:00 app[web.1]: > shopping-cart-app@0.1.0 start /app
2017-10-08T20:06:22.944621+00:00 app[web.1]:
2017-10-08T20:06:22.944637+00:00 app[web.1]: > concurrently "npm run server" "npm run client"
2017-10-08T20:06:22.944637+00:00 app[web.1]:
2017-10-08T20:06:22.951908+00:00 app[web.1]: sh: 1: concurrently: not found
2017-10-08T20:06:22.957587+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2017-10-08T20:06:22.957261+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! file sh
2017-10-08T20:06:22.957843+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno ENOENT
2017-10-08T20:06:22.959735+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
2017-10-08T20:06:22.958098+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! syscall spawn
2017-10-08T20:06:22.959544+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! shopping-cart-app@0.1.0 start: `concurrently "npm run server" "npm run client"`
2017-10-08T20:06:22.960008+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2017-10-08T20:06:22.960225+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the shopping-cart-app@0.1.0 start script.
2017-10-08T20:06:22.966218+00:00 app[web.1]:
2017-10-08T20:06:22.966570+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2017-10-08T20_06_22_962Z-debug.log
2017-10-08T20:06:22.960452+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2017-10-08T20:06:22.966432+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2017-10-08T20:06:23.060706+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

I can run the app on my localhost but it crashes in heroku. It seems that I am having issues with the concurrently package while starting app in heroku. I used `npm i -S concurrently` but it downloads under dev dependancies. Is there some type of setting in Heroku that I need to change to use concurrently?

Comment: check if you using the the same packages when you initialize your objects.
you can initialize an object and don't have to use it even if its not installed in the dependencies.
I initialize node mailer didn't use it and it was not installed in the dependencies and everything worked well locally only.

Answer (score 5):

```
apt-get install nodejs-legacy
npm install -g tsc
npm install -g concurrently
npm install -g typescript
```

try this command